# Land on marketing domain, proceed to members-only domain. How to filter these?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, reporting

We would like to filter out (from our monthly GA reporting stats) those site visits where a user lands on our marketing domain and then immediately clicks our "Member Login" hyperlink (simple anchor tag) to navigate to our members-only site.

Our members-only domain is a subdomain (i.e., members.example.com) of the primary marketing (www.example.com) domain.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

1. Create a custom event, call it using the onclick attribute of the anchor tag (of the outbound link), as per [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en), using the JavaScript code below
2. Create an exclusion for that event using advanced segments

   ```
   var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
      if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
        ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
          'transport': 'beacon',
          'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Google analytics object was not found!");
      }
   }

   jQuery(function() {
      var url = "https://members.example.com";

      jQuery("a[href *= 'members.example.com']").on('click', function() {
        trackOutboundLink(url);
      });
   });
   ```